# Elevation and point data

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, elevation

On arcmap 10.1, I have elevation data that is shown as contour lines (polylines) i also have point data showing the distribution on certain animals. I want to run some kind of statistical analysis to see at what height the animals are most commonly found at, how would i do that/what tools would i use? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the Spatial Analyst Extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first thing to do is creating a DEM based on your contour lines. If you have 3D analyst, you can build a TIN, and if you have spatial analyst you can use "topo to raster". Then you can extract the values using extract value to point.

If you don't have the extension, either you use "spatial join" to extract the values of the closest polyline (in this case, you are not very precise), or you do it QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

firstly make a raster data (i.e. DEM or TIN) by 3D analysis tools or also you can make a DEM by Topo to Raster.
After that in Arc toolbox go to spatial analysis tools-------select extraction-------extract values to points.
In order to this select input points data and input Raster data set the path of your output data.

Run the process, you will find the height for every points.